# How to create a new (unique) CustomerID if NA?

Tags: r

I have a set containing Invoice_Date, CustomerID, Invoice_Sum, Number.

```
              InvoiceDate CustomerID Invoice_Sum Number
 1     01/02/2011 08:23      15240     312.900     14
 2     01/02/2011 08:31      14911     797.770     45
 3     01/02/2011 09:01      14496     234.470     14
 4     01/02/2011 09:36      17147     409.500     18
 5     01/02/2011 09:38      12626     -45.300      2
 6     01/02/2011 09:38      17675     698.600     22
 ...
 19    01/02/2011 10:56         NA     669.460     88
```

There are a few missing customer IDs, but from the exact time it is clear that it is the same order. 
I know want to make a command like: 
IF NA -> assign a new customerID (any number, which has not been used already)

Is there a way in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do not say if there are any restrictions on how CustomerID is supposed to be generated. I am going to assume that you want a randomly selected number between 10000 and 20000 that is not on the list of existing CustomerIDs.  So ...

```
## Set up your example data
df = read.table(text="              InvoiceDate CustomerID Invoice_Sum Number
 1     '01/02/2011 08:23'      15240     312.900     14
 2     '01/02/2011 08:31'      14911     797.770     45
 3     '01/02/2011 09:01'      14496     234.470     14
 4     '01/02/2011 09:36'      17147     409.500     18
 5     '01/02/2011 09:38'      12626     -45.300      2
 6     '01/02/2011 09:38'      17675     698.600     22
 19    '01/02/2011 10:56'         NA     669.460     88",
header=TRUE)

NeedID = which(is.na(df$CustomerID))
df$CustomerID[NeedID] = 
    sample(setdiff(10000:19999, df$CustomerID), length(NeedID))
```